# SQL Server: How to set column alias from another table during select?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table 1:

```
DB1, DB2, DB3, DB4, DB5, Some other identifiers
```

Table 2:

```
EnumText, EnumValue, Some other identifiers
```

What I want to do is to:-

1. Select data from Table 1
2. During Select, change the alias of columns DB1 to DB5 using the Data in Table 2's EnumText column where EnumValue will contain DB1 to DB5.

A sample command would be:

```
Select 
    DB1 as [Select EnumText from Table2 where EnumValue='DB1'], 
    DB2, DB3 
from Table1
```

This command won't work but I hope you people got the idea.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have dynamic aliases without dynamic SQL. If you did change the resultset column names, how do you access them via name? (I wouldn't use index because it will break)

So, you can add a fixed column to describe it. And read *that*

```
Select 
    DB1, foo.EnumText AS DB1EnumText, 
    DB2, 
    DB3 
from 
    Table1
    CROSS JOIN
    (Select EnumText from Table2 where EnumValue='DB1') foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
But there is another hurdle in this option, what if we do not want to manually key in 'DB1', 'DB2' etc in EnumValue='DB1'.

EnumValue actually stores DB1, DB2, DB3.

Comment: @Venomal: Again, you can't without dynamic SQL because you can't join on the *column names* from table1 to the *values* in table2

Comment: okay! thanks. I wonder if parameters can help us here or not.