# Can I create Dynamic Column Names in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I two tables, one table contains the names of columns, the other table contains the actual data that I need to display in a report. The data and columns are linked by a column key.

Is there a way to build a select statement that can use the column name from the column table for the actual temp table column?

Something like this;

```
Select A.value AS B.ColumnName
```

Simply put Can I create a table column name based on the value in another table in sql?

Comment: You'd need to do some form of Dynamic SQL, to concatenate the list of (result) column names, and some pretty weird searching of your original string to figure out the names you needed.  But what's actually running this (language, framework, etc)?  You may have a **much** easier time leaving your actual column names alone, and simply doing the replace in your application, when it's time to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do it without using dynamic SQL as mentioned question that can be useful for you.

[SQL Server: How to set column alias from another table during select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361596/sql-server-how-to-set-column-alias-from-another-table-during-select)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in DB2 ZOS

Comment: Right John, but still same answer for DB2- even Oracle. You need to use dynamic SQL to reach the requirement.